# Setting mailgun variables in template using Python request

Tags: python, python-requests, mailgun

I want to set the value of a variable using a header attribute (as documented [here](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/user_manual.html#attaching-data-to-messages)). My Python code for sending:

```
import requests
res = requests.post(
    "https://api.eu.mailgun.net/v3/mg.domain.de/messages",
    auth=("api", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxx"),
    headers = {
        "X-Mailgun-Variables": {"{'href_target': 'test'}"}
    },
    data={
        "from": "noreply@domain.de",
        "to": ["target@email.com"],
        "subject": "Testsubject",
        "template": "confirm-email-de",
    })
```

I'm using the `{{href_target}}` in my template. While the online preview correctly displays the value of `href_target` (which is "test_href_target") instead of the handlebar syntax, this does not work when using the API.

Thanks!

Comment: As it looks like you are using the HTTP API, you can only attach data using `v:my_message_id=123` in this scenario.

Comment: Updated your answer with sample code how I got it to work - thanks for pointing the right direction!

Comment: Hooray! Glad you got where you needed to. Best of luck with the rest of your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`X-Mailgun-Variables` header is only for adding this data via the SMTP API. You need to use the instructions for the HTTP API. Use:

```
data = {
    ...
    "v:href_target": "https://google.com"
}
```

And skip the `headers`.

Comment: Tried that already: `InvalidHeader: Value for header {X-Mailgun-Variables: {'href_target': 'test'}} must be of type str or bytes, not <class 'dict'>` - Thanks for the reply anyways!

Comment: Well, that's the only format it is allowed to be:
`X-Mailgun-Variables: {"first_name": "John", "last_name": "Smith"}`
Perhaps you are including it in the wrong location? You might need to put it under `data`.

Comment: Neither `"X-Mailgun-Variables": {"href_target": 'target'}` nor `"h:X-Mailgun-Variables": {"href_target": 'target'}` (both in in `data`) worked. The first yields an email without the variable being set, the second yields a bounce of type "other" - and I don't know any way to debug this further. I've been bruteforcing since quite some time...

Comment: Ah, the docs say you need to be sending via SMTP to use these as sending options.